# Bootstrap: Element in row not align to the left of the page

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have created a page on a view (using mvc).  Using bootstrap and adding html element for search and other user activity.  The items are in a bootstrap row and  I expect download and refresh button to align to right but some how they are sticking to the left side.   Please see the code below. I am trying to find what is it wrong with the code. Can someone take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong. It will help me understand where I am making a mistake. The code is relevant to the "Check Log" row showing in the image.

```
   <div class="container-fluid">

     <div class="row">

      <div class=" col-xs-8">

        <h5>Check Logs</h5>

    </div>

    <div class=" col-xs-2 float-right">

        <input type="submit" name="response" value="Download" formaction=@Url.Action("DownLoad") 
      formmethod="post" onclick="return confirmDataSet()" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark btn- 
              sm rounded-0" />

      

    </div>

    <div class=" col-xs-2 float-right">

            <a asp-action="Index" title="Refresh" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark btn-sm 
              rounded- 
             0"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></a>

           </div>

        </div>

      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: why tag bootstrap 4 because bootstrap 4 haven't classes of xs?

Comment: is it bootstrap 4 or 3?

Comment: it is bootstrap 4 and I believe it has support xs for grid (columns).  I use Visual Studio and intelisence  provide me the option for xs.  But I did notice it doesn't give me the option to work with xs when working with margin left or margin right.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-xs-8">
      <h5>Check Logs</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="col-xs-2 float-right">
        <input type="submit" name="response" value="Download" formaction=@Url.Action( "DownLoad") formmethod="post" onclick="return confirmDataSet()" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark btn- 
              sm rounded-0" />
      </div>
      <div class=" col-xs-2 float-right">
        <a asp-action="Index" title="Refresh" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark btn-sm 
              rounded- 
             0"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nisharg,  It is showing the download button in another row. Not in the row of check logs.   also not able to see the refresh button.